# how do design the database tables for file download statistics

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, statistics

I have the web application where i am serving file downloads in php.
All is working fine and i have the download column in `file field` where i increment it.

But i want to have full statictics of downloads like how many downloads on `each day` or in `month` or `time of day` or from `which location`

But i am not able o find how to design the mysql tables for that. Do i need to log every download request in database for that. Any design pattern or example of that in real world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table similar to the following:

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| download_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| created     | timestamp           | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| filename    | varchar(32)         | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| ip          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Each time a file is downloaded, insert the filename and IP address into the appropriate columns (the other two will autofill with the correct information).  Then you can execute queries against this table to gather your analytics.  For instance:

If you wanted to see how many downloads there were in June of 2013:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_downloads FROM file_download WHERE DATE(created) BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30';
```

If you wanted to see how many times the file "somefile.zip" was downloaded since it was posted:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_downloads FROM file_download WHERE filename = 'somefile.zip';
```

Or if you wanted to see how many times "somefile.zip" was downloaded, excluding duplicates downloaded by the same visitor:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_downloads FROM file_download WHERE filename = 'somefile.zip' GROUP BY ip;
```

By logging an entry for each download, you have a great deal of flexibility in the type of data you can analyze.  The amount of space that each entry takes will be minimal, and will give you access to a lot more options than incrementing a single value for each download.

Answer (score 1):

Before you respond with the file download, you can add a bit of code to log the request details for the purpose of analytics. On DB Design options:

- Store just the count and increment it as and when you serve a download. Consumes little space, but provides less flexibility in analytics and reporting.
- Storing Individual Downloads: You can store, timestamps, fields and even the requesting IPs that can all be very useful in your analytics, but this approach will consume significant space.
- You can also meet mid way, like storing the last one months data in full, for instance, and then archiving them out of your DB into a zip file and just store the incremented, categorized data for your reports.

You can also use something like [Server Side Google Analytics](https://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/)